# How can I access the World within my System? (Rust+Legion)

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust+Legion so this might be a really dumb question, but I haven't been able to find a way to access the [World](https://docs.rs/legion/0.4.0/legion/world/struct.World.html) within a system.

I'd like to make a query in a system, but because a mutable reference to the world is required to iterate thru the query, I can't figure out the best way to handle this.

I've been able to pass references to shared resources, but not the world itself.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is this not a common pattern within ECS?

(I'm using [Legion](https://github.com/amethyst/legion) 0.4.0)

```rust
use legion::*;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct ComponentOne {}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct ComponentTwo {}

fn main() {

    let mut world = World::default();
    let mut resources = Resources::default();

    world.push(( ComponentOne {}, ));

    let mut schedule = Schedule::builder()
        .add_system(do_stuff_system())
        .build();

    schedule.execute(&mut world, &mut resources);

    //
    // some sort of game loop would go here
    //
}

#[system(for_each)]
fn do_stuff(c1: &mut ComponentOne) {

    // GOAL: query entities with ComponentTwo,
    //       then iterate thru them and do stuff
    let mut query = Read::<ComponentTwo>::query();

    // ISSUE: I can't iterate thru the query without
    //        &world, but I can't find a way to pass
    //        &world to this system
    for (c2) in query.iter(&world) { // <-- doesn't work (world not found)
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `SubWorld` and `Commands` (to change the world state after the current batch of systems runs) by simply adding them as an arguments to a System.

```
use legion::world::SubWorld;
use legion::systems::CommandBuffer;


#[system]
#[read_component(Entity)]
#[read_component(Item)]
#[write_component(Inventory)]
#[write_component(Equipped)]
#[read_component(Point)]
#[read_component(Player)]
#[write_component(Time)]
pub fn equipment_input(
    ecs: &mut SubWorld,
    commands: &mut CommandBuffer,
    #[resource] key_opt: &Option<InputCommand>,
    #[resource] turn_states: &mut TurnStateStack,
    #[resource] log: &mut GameLog,
) {
...
}
```

I learned this from [Hand-On Rust book](https://pragprog.com/titles/hwrust/hands-on-rust/). Now that I think of it, there is some documentation in [the Legion API reference](https://docs.rs/legion/0.4.0/legion/attr.system.html), but I never found it before I knew what to look for.